# Vyper convert TypeMismatch error

Tags: exceptions, vyper

I'm trying to use convert in Vyper but get the following error:

vyper.exceptions.TypeMismatch: Expecting one of ('num_literal', 'int128', 'int256', 'bytes32', 'Bytes', 'address', 'bool', 'decimal') for argument 1 of convert

```
def forLoop() -> (uint256):
    x: uint256 = 0
    for i in [1, 2, 3]:
        x += convert(i, uint256)
    return x
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it works just fine, using compiler version 0.2.8.

Maybe you should try adding this to the top of your contract:

```
# @version ^0.2.8
```

Maybe your function needs the decorator to specify it's visibility, such as:

```
@external
def forLoop() -> (uint256):
    x: uint256 = 0
    for i in [1, 2, 3]:
        x += convert(i, uint256)
    return x
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert i into uint256 on version 0.2.12

Try as follows.

```
def forLoop() -> (uint256):
x: uint256 = 0
for i in [1, 2, 3]:
    x += i
return x
```